# Programming Beginner - Java program adapted from C

Tags: java, newtons-method

I'm brand new at writing programs in any language and I'm trying to write a simple Newton-Raphson method which I think works in C (haven't compiled but going from a previous example that did work so I'm making this assumption) but realised that I don't know exactly how to call a method from Java... I'm getting these errors:

```
NewtRaphEx.java:5: class, interface, or enum expected
double f = (double); 
^
NewtRaphEx.java:6: class, interface, or enum expected
double df = (double); 
^
NewtRaphEx.java:39: class, interface, or enum expected
double f(double x) {
^
```

I assume I'm calling the f and df methods incorrectly? This is not for a homework question, simply my own practice!

My program so far is:

```
/* Newton Raphson Method*/

import Scanner.java.util; 

double f = (double); 
double df = (double); 

public class NewtRaphEx {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        double xn, e_allow, fn, fnew, eps, dfn, dfnew; 
        int n;
        int nMax = 10000;

        e_allow = 0.001;
        xn = 0.6;

        while (eps <= e_allow || n < nMax) {
            for (n = 0; n <= nMax; n++) {
                fn = f(xn); 
                dfn = df(xn);
                dx = -(fn / dfn); 
                xnew = xn + dx; 
                eps = Math.abs(dx / xn);
                n = n + 1; 
                System.out.println("N" + "\t" + "X" + "\t" + "F(x)" + "\t" + "dF(x)" + "\t" + "delX" + "\t" + "X_new" + "\t" + "Epsilon");
                System.out.println(n + "\t" + xn + "\t" + fn + "\t" + dfn + "\t" + dx + "\t" + xnew + "\t" + eps);
            }
        }
    }
}



// Creating Function f = x - cos(3.5x)

double f(double x) {
    return (x - cos(3.5 * x)) 
}

double df (double x) {
    return (1 + sin(3.5 * x))
}
```

Comment: You have declared variables outside of the class

Comment: You should review a tutorial on Java programming. Start here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Comment: The only method I see is called `main`.... which method are you talking about?

Comment: So why is this tagged C please? I don't see no C here ...

Comment: OT: You might (also?) like to read about properly indenting code.

Comment: Just for the record; outside your programming errors, your derivative `df` is also wrong. ;)

Comment: @alk because OP was trying to adapt C code to Java...

Comment: Ok so I changed it according to suggestions and have it working now EXCEPT I can't seem to get out of an infinite loop!! I would have thought that the while loop would stop it but it isn't working... Just trying to put updated code in here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Methods `f` and `df` are outside the class. They must be declared inside it. They should be `static` since they are not bound to an instance and you will call them from a static method.

This `double f = (double);` is illegal. You must provide a value or nothing `double f;`

`sin` and `cos` should be `java.lang.Math.sin` and `java.lang.Math.cos` unless you use static import.

Answer (score 1):

Java differs from C/C++ in many respects, including (particular to this issue) that you need most everything *within* a class definition e.g.

```
package ...

import ...

public class NewtRaphEx {
   ...
}
```

So the package defines the namespace, the imports define what namespaces are within scope and then the class definition (the same name as the `.java` filename) contains everything else. Note that you can only have *one* public class within a `.java` file (Java is restrictive in this fashion)

Given your question above I think a good starting point is to put everything within a `main()` method (analagous to `main` in a C program).

```
public class NewtRaphEx {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       // put your code here...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You intended to declare 2 functions, `f` and `df` before the `main` function, then define both `f` and `df`. You're allowed to do this kind of things in C, **but this is not C, is Java**.

In Java, you can only declare classes and interfaces at the top level, and the methods are defined inside them. So, these *functions* are invalid, along with their definitions below the class:

```
import Scanner.java.util; 

//invalid
double f = (double);
//invalid
double df = (double); 

public class NewtRaphEx {
    //class content...
}
//invalid
// Creating Function f = x - cos(3.5x)
double f(double x) {
    return (x - cos(3.5 * x)) 
}
//invalid
double df (double x) {
    return (1 + sin(3.5 * x))
}
```

To make your application work, one way would be to redefine these functions as `static` methods inside your class.

```
import Scanner.java.util; 

public class NewtRaphEx {
    //valid
    // Creating Function f = x - cos(3.5x)
    static double f(double x) {
        return (x - cos(3.5 * x)) 
    }
    //valid
    static double df (double x) {
        return (1 + sin(3.5 * x))
    }
    //class content...
}
```

I highly recommend you to review the basics of Java programming by following [The Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Comment: Thanks, I have reviewed the basics in java and can write basic programs, the problem is that I also need to learn C at the same time so am getting confused on specific call methods and don't fully understand how to call or use methods in java but I'm trying suggestions on here and will see if they work!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my last answer (I didn't read carefuly).

There are 2 problems:

(1) d and df are functions/method, not variables. Then, you can safely delete the top declarations since the functions/method are declared at the bottom of the file:

```
//Delete this
double f = (double);
double df = (double);
```

(2) You are trying to call a member function(f and df) inside a static function (main). That won't work. Then, you should declare those functions as static and move it inside the class:

```
 static double f(double x) {
        return (x - cos(3.5 * x)) 
    }

    static double df (double x) {
        return (1 + sin(3.5 * x))
    }
}
```